# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add'), Type error on "classlist.add"

Tags: javascript, button, addeventlistener

I am using a button to add a class to an div but I keep getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add').

I have looked around the rest of Stack Overflow and I found a similar poster with a similar problem. Here's my code stripped to bare bones:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <div class="name-row">Hello!</div>
    <button type="button" onclick="clear()" id="clearButton">Clear</button>
    
    <script>
        document.getElementById('clearButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
                let allNamesElm = document.getElementsByClassName("name-row");
                allNamesElm.classList.add("showing");
                window.alert("Cleared!");
                console.log("cleared");
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try to explicity call my function, it just does not execute the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <div class="name-row">Hello!</div>
    <button type="button" onclick="clear()" id="clearButton">Clear</button>
    
    <script>
        function clear() {
                let allNamesElm = document.getElementsByClassName("name-row");
                allNamesElm.classList.add("showing");
                window.alert("Cleared!");
                console.log("cleared");
            };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It's probably a careless error, but I have tried to fix it and it does not work :(.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention that `allNamesElm` is not an element itself, it's a HTMLCollection(an array-like object). You need to access the specific element, which in your case is the first element in the collection.